# re_comm run issue

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed RoboEarth but am having problems running re_comm as detailed here wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack/Tutorials/Using%20recorded%20models%20for%20object%20detection
The output

> rmb209@rmb209-Studio-1555:~/ros/stacks/knowrob$ rosrun re_comm run

> rospack Error: stack/package re_comm not found

Could anyone suggest a reason or solution for this?

I have finished wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack the installation instructions here, which seem to have built without any issues.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146541/re_comm-run-issue/) by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on 2014-03-31**:
This is on fuerte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message means that ROS cannot find the re_comm package. Please make sure that it is part of your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. If you used rosinstall or rosws for installation, don't forget to source the setup.bash again.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on 2014-04-01**:
Following this I then had to re-follow the setting java path answer in a previous question
and set JAVA_HOME

Thank you for your assistance.